# MKStoreManager object overreleased while already deallocating

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I have a Mac app that is crashing on start and the console shows below error

> MKStoreManager object overreleased while already deallocating; break
>   on objc_overrelease_during_dealloc_error to debug

This error only shows up with new XCode 8 and macOS Sierra.